# Is font-family: SegoeUI, 'Segoe UI', "Open Sans"; a stack that does not require a license?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I understand similar questions have already been asked but I have not been able find one with a clearn and accepted answer.

It's my understanding that the SegoeUI font is included with Windows 7/8. Assuming that I do not use font-face or download the font then is the following font stack allowed:

```
font-family: SegoeUI, 'Segoe UI', "Open Sans";
```

From what I understand this will use SegoeUI only IF it is already available and obviously will not work on Apple or other.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues.

Comment: Check the information provided by the copyright holder of the font, or contact them, or consult your lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

When you give multiple `font-family`, you are actually providing fallbacks to the first font type. In your case `SegoeUI` is the primary font and the others are for fallback 
If SegoeUI isn't present, then use the next one. This cycle will continue till it reaches a font that's installed on a machine. If none is installed, `sans-serif` will be used.

You must add `Helvetica` (Apple font), so that Apple users can see the content in Helvetica.

So, your css should become like:

```
font-family: SegoeUI, 'Segoe UI', "Open Sans",Helvetica;
```

Also, there won't be any copyright infringes, because every Apple product comes with pre-installed font `Helvetica`. And in  recent years, every Windows is coming preinstalled with `SegoeUI`

Answer (score 0):

SegoeUI is installed by default on Windows 7/8. So any machine running OSX that hasn't explicitly downloaded and installed SegoeUI won't load it.

However as you have specified "Open Sans" that would be the next 'fallback' the system will go to. So people running OSX (or Linux/other OS's) will fall back to "Open Sans".

The very last fallback people use is generally "Sans Serif" or "Serif" depending on the type of font the first font is.